# Как с помощью custom validator сделать проверку двух полей, password и confirmPassword?

Tags: php, symfony

```php
<?php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use App\DTO\SignupDTO;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class ConfirmPasswordValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $signupFormPassword;

    public function __construct(SignupDTO $signupFormPassword)
    {
        $this->signupFormPassword = $signupFormPassword;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {

        if ($this->signupFormPassword->getPassword($value) != $this->signupFormPassword->getConfirmPassword($value))
        {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{ value }}', $value)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }   
}
```

аргумент $value принимает значение только первого свойства. Как правильно применить это ко второму свойству?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был найден собственно в самой документации symfony. Ссылка, https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator

Прежде всего, нужно было добавить метод getTargets() к Constraint.class, который может иметь весь класс в качестве своей области действия:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ConfirmPassword extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Поле пароль не совпадает с полем подтверждения пароля.';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return \get_class($this).'Validator';
    }

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

При этом метод валидатора validate() получает объект в качестве первого аргумента:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class ConfirmPasswordValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {       
        if ($value->getPassword() != $value->getConfirmPassword())
        {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->atPath('password')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }   
}
```

Валидатор ограничения класса применяется к самому классу, а не к свойству:

```php
<?php

namespace App\DTO;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;
use App\Validator\Constraints as ConfirmAssert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ConfirmAssert\ConfirmPassword
 */
final class SignupDTO
{
}
```